# Fragment to Activity issue

Tags: java, android

I have an issue of opening an `Activity` through `Fragment` can any help me with this?

```
public ReserveFragment(View view) {
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.reserveBlazer);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BlazerDatabase.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}}
```

Comment: `BlazerDatabase` most likely isn't an `instanceof Activity`or `getActivity()` returns `null`... and I've voted to close this, because it is quite unclear what you are asking (and with high probability, this also is a duplicate question). see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please describe what your ` have an issue of opening` means. Vote to close this because the question is unclear.

Comment: Are you asking for `getActivity().startActivity()`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your problem is solved by using `getActivity()` to start activity.Because you need instacne of running activity to start activity from fragment.

```
public ReserveFragment(View view) {
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.reserveBlazer);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BlazerDatabase.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }}
```